# Draw half empty rectangle

Tags: graphics

How can I draw an half or a third filled rectangle? I want to make one rectangle frame with a unity width and then filled it according to a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Take a look at `EdgeForm` and `FaceForm` and draw two rectangles.

Comment: @Kuba is there a ColorFunction analogue for this case (can be used as Graphics primitive)?

Comment: @happyfish there is an option `VertexColors` for a `Polygon`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Rectangle[], Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 0.5}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or indeed, if you want to be able to change the filling dynamically, you can wrap a manipulate around it.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Rectangle[], Black, 
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, a}]}], {a, 0, 1, 0.05}]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 9):

For fun

**Example**

```
DynamicModule[
 {fill},
 fill = .5;
 Panel @ Column[{
    Slider[Dynamic @ fill, {0, 1}],
    Graphics[{
      {FaceForm @ White, EdgeForm @ {Thick, Black}, Rectangle[{0, 0}]},
      {FaceForm @ Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, Dynamic @ fill}]}
      }]
    },
   Alignment -> Center]
 ]
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: +1 because it is a less taxing dynamic routine, and I agree that Mathematica is fun.